# window.location vs window.open issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of code for a drop-down list url redirection which works fine how ever I need to open the urls in a new tab, I have done some searching around and found the alternative for window.location is window.open but so I changed the code to what I think would have been logical but I know somethings not right but I don't currently have the knowledge to fix it.

```
 $(function () {
        // get your select element and listen for a change event on it
        $('#selectEl').change(function () {
            // set the window's location property to the value of the option the user has selected
            //window.location = $(this).val();
              window.open($(this).val(););
        });
    });
```

HTNL

```
<form name="form1">
                        <select name="select" size="1" id="selectEl">
                            <option value="">I would like to login to...</option>
                            <option value="client_login">Secure Login</option>
                             <option value="https://login.xero.com/">Xero Login</option>
                            <option value="https://secure.saasu.com/a/login">Saasu Login</option>
                           <option value="https://businessaccounting.banklinkonline.com">BankLink Login</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
```

Comment: no need for the `;` inside the () of `open` in `window.open($(this).val(););`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that extra `;`

```
 window.open($(this).val());
```

Demo  `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/21/show/

Comment: Thanks, just as simple as that!